# Universal approximation theorem in the $\mathcal{C}^1$-norm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, approximation

Let's say we are given a one dimensional FFNN $f_N: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with hidden dimension $N$
$$f_N(x)=W_1\phi(W_2x+b_2)+b_1$$
with $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{N },b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{N},W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{ N},b_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{ }$. Let $f$ be continuous in $[0,1]$. If $\phi$ is not polynomial we know the UAT holds
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 : \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \|f_N-f\|_{C^0}\leq \varepsilon$$

However, this is based on the $C^0$ norm $\|f_N-f\|_{C^0}=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_N-f|$.

My question is the following: Is the theorem still true if we replace the $C^0$-norm by the $C^1$-norm ($\|f_N-f\|_{C^1}=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}(|f_N-f|+|f_N'-f'|)$)?

Comment: If you would not use obscure acronyms like "FFNN" and "UAT" then this might be a good question for [math.se].

Comment: Ok, then can you move it to mathematics?

Comment: I have suggested that you should do that after expanding your acronyms: that will give it a better reception there.